# How to upload a static copy of a pages HTML to S3

Tags: 7, caching

I have a need to upload a copy of a rendered output of a URL to Amazon S3 when it is edited and published.

By this I mean if I was to edit /brand-a/page-1 on a site, I would like the full rendered output of that page as seen by an unauthenticated user to be uploaded to /brand-a/page-1 in a S3 bucket. Essentually using Drupal as a content publishing platform offloading all delivery to the end user to Amazon S3.

[image: Publishing Sequence]

I am comfortable using the Amazon S3 + AWSSDK + Libraries plugin for handling of media, I have not been able to find a plugin that covers off my requirements highlighted in red in the above diagram.

Comment: If you are comfortable with the various AWS portions, I am sure it would be fairly trivial to use something like `$foo=file_get_contents('http://www.yourhost.com/brand-a/page-1')` to transfer `$foo` up into a bucket.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma, I am comfortable building it, however in an ideal world there would be a module out there that already does this; I assume from your comment that this is not an ideal world?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed up the transfer process you could use [HTTPRL](https://drupal.org/project/httprl/) to send the data to S3 in a non blocking request. You can also use it to do threading.

Comment: Thanks, good library, will come in useful at some point.